# Assign variable from inner function to outer scope

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make this code works, but I'm on the rocks with the functions scopes.

This is my code so far:

```
var Canoe = function () {
    this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'models/canoe.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var canoeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
        canoeMesh.castShadow = true;
        canoeMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        this.mesh.add(canoeMesh);
    });
```

}

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

How can I assign the `mesh` I created in the inner function to the outer variable?

Comment: The problem is that `this` is not what your code expects it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to put mesh in a variable defined in the function:

```
var Canoe = function () {
var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
this.mesh = mesh;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'models/canoe.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
    var canoeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
    canoeMesh.castShadow = true;
    canoeMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    mesh.add(canoeMesh);
});
```

*Someone could write a book on how `this` works in javascript.  It's often not what you expect.*

Answer (score 0):

Before loader.load() add

```
var that = this;
```

In your load function put

```
that.mesh.add(canoeMesh);
```

Problem is that "this" inside loader.load() points to somewhere else than outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a couple options.  One, is to assign `this` to another variable, like so:

```
var self = this;
var Canoe = function () {
    self.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'models/canoe.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var canoeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
        canoeMesh.castShadow = true;
        canoeMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        self.mesh.add(canoeMesh);
    });
}
```

Another option, if you have a transpiler, would be to use an arrow function, which retains lexical `this`:

```
var Canoe = () => {
    this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'models/canoe.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var canoeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
        canoeMesh.castShadow = true;
        canoeMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        this.mesh.add(canoeMesh);
    });
}
```